# Swashbuckle: Multiple [SwaggerResponse] with the same status code but different description/model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm writing a demonstration shopping cart API and I've come across a situation where I can return NotFound for multiple reasons (either a cart item isn't found or the cart itself is not found). I want to return a Swagger description for both cases. I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(CartNotFoundResponse), Description = "Cart not found (code=1)")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(ItemNotFoundResponse), Description = "Item not found (code=104)")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteItemWithSKUAsync(Guid cartId, string sku)
    {
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible with the current implementation:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs#L29

As you can see the responses is a dictionary and the key is the StatusCode.

My recommendation: use a more generic class that can cover both of you cases (CartNotFound & ItemNotFound)

Answer (score -1):

Consider not caring about:

1. The cart not being found;
2. The item not being found or already being deleted.

Just respond with a NoContent whether or not you actually deleted something or not. If it is not there, it is not there, which is exactly what you wanted to happen.

Why do I advice to do this?
Because it makes your API less complex and it keeps you from having to think about the situation where either the cart or the cart item is not there at all.

But what if my DB throws when I try to delete something that is not there?
Just catch that and pretend you deleted it. Make your API respond with NoContent, because there really is no content.

Comment: Consider not caring? That's just a bad advice, not a valid answer.

Comment: Why? He wants to delete something that is not there or no longer there....

Comment: Disclaimer: it's debatable. On one hand checking if there is something to delete before deleting is an [anti pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/378671) and it is slower (since two queries vs one), on the other is making your code dependent on DB to fail so you can handle the failure. Either way, OP clearly checks if there is something to delete, since he uses types of response such as `CartNotFoundResponse` or `ItemNotFoundResponse`, so in the context of this particular question, it is not a valid answer.

Comment: "On the other is making your code dependent on DB to fail so you can handle the failure."
Since when does a DELETE statement result in a failure when the record is not there?

I am fully aware what the OP is doing.
That is why I suggested to relax his API a bit and to not bother about the Cart or CartItem not or no longer being there.
It really makes the API a lot simpeler and easier to understand and use.

Comment: Lastly, I really do not like the tone in your comments.
My advice is not bad advice at all and honestly it is a valid suggestion to the problem the OP describes.
It takes away unneeded API complexity and the result is that the NotFound responses are no longer required at all.
He can just respond with NoContent.

Honestly, I feel people reacting the way you do make StackOverflow a less nicer place.
So please, consider responding in a more friendly way in the future.

Comment: SQL databases will most likely just return 0 as a number of affected rows after executing DELETE query. But OP does not specify what kind of DB he uses, whether is it SQL or No-SQL DB engine, neither he shows in what manner he performs the removal. With that said, you cannot assume that DB will not fail, because you don't know what type it is — therefore, how will it behave when requested for deleting an entry that may not exist anymore. Yet, OP most likely uses some kind of relational DB engine, so I guess my point of assuming failure after DELETE is most probably void here.